# Infragistics UltraChart comes up as red-x broken image

Tags: infragistics, broken-image

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but when I try to display an UltraChart, it just shows a box with a red-x in the corner.

I'm currently just trying to implement example code for a simple bar chart:

```
<igchart:UltraChart ID="barchartData" runat="server">
</igchart:UltraChart>
```

And in code behind:

```
    DataTable mydata = new DataTable();
    // Define the columns and their names
    mydata.Columns.Add("Series Labels", typeof(string));
    mydata.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof(int));
    mydata.Columns.Add("Column B", typeof(int));
    mydata.Columns.Add("Column C", typeof(int));
    mydata.Columns.Add("Column D", typeof(int));
    // Add the rows of data
    mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "Series A", 1, 4, 10, 4 });
    mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "Series B", 3, 6, 4, 5 });
    mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "Series C", 5, 8, 6, 7 });
    mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "Series D", 7, 10, 7, 7 });
    barchartData.DataSource = mydata;
    barchartData.DataBind();
```

This should result in the following:
[image]

However, I get this:
[image]

Note:  I am sure the data is getting to the table because, even though I only get the broken image box, as I move the mouse over it, I see the tooltip numbers when I hover over where a bar should be.

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you got the placeholder for the image because the image wasn't found or there was a server error.  If you use a tool like fiddler or the Network tools of your browser to see the actual response from the server you will get more information.

As far as resolving the issue, it will depend on what the response was from the server and what image deployment strategy you are using for the WebChart, you may want to read more on this in the help: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Chart_Image_Deployment_in_WebChart.html